# Максимальная длина REST запроса в Retrofit

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

Есть следующий интерфейс

```
@Streaming
    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Authorization: Bearer token"})
    @POST("speech/v1/tts:synthesize")
    Observable<ResponseBody> getSpeechOgg(@Query("text") String text, @Query("emotion") String emotion);
```

В параметре text необходимо передавать текст длиной не более 5000 символов (Требование Яндекс.Облака). Однако, ещё даже не приблизившись к этому лимиту ~2000 символов при отправке REST запроса я получаю следующую ошибку

```
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: okhttp3.internal.http2.ConnectionShutdownException
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err: okhttp3.internal.http2.ConnectionShutdownException
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection.newStream(Http2Connection.java:248)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection.newStream(Http2Connection.java:231)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec.writeRequestHeaders(Http2Codec.java:117)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:50)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:225)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:92)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:42)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-17 20:36:01.567 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154)
08-17 20:36:01.568 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
08-17 20:36:01.568 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
08-17 20:36:01.568 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
08-17 20:36:01.568 trelico.ru.allcastmvvm W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

При меньшем количестве символов все обрабатывается совершенно нормально.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`query` передаются в адресной строке, которая в свою очередь имеет ограничение длины.
Но судя по коду вы хотите отправить форму, а это делается чуть иначе:

```
@Streaming
@Headers("Authorization: Bearer token")
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("speech/v1/tts:synthesize")
Observable<ResponseBody> getSpeechOgg(@Field("text") String text, @Field("emotion") String emotion);
```